# two different settings.gradle file intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have one project, it has a `settings.gradle file`, I also have a second `fred-settings.gradle` file that is used in a certain specific builds using a **gradle switch '-c'**.

How do I tell **intellij** to only use the non default file : '`fred-settings.gradle`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should most probably not use different settings files anyway. This is deprecated in Gradle, besides that the IDE just not (yet?) supports custom settings files.

You could for example have the logic for both cases in the default `settings.gradle(.kts)` and then select via project property or any other way which logic-path to follow in the settings script.

You could then change this condition, e.g. by setting the project property in `gradle.properties` in your `<GRADLE_USER_HOME>`, and start the import.

Comment: I didn't realize it was deprecacted, thnks

Answer (score 1):

You can not specify different settings.gradle file for IDE import or build action, see related request: [IDEA-129806](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129806/Import-project-of-custom-named-gradle-settings-file-does-not-work) But you can specify it if you are using Gradle Run/Debug Configuration in Arguments field.